# What kind of iteration is this?

Tags: javascript, iterator

Given an index of `5`, and an array size of `10`, this array is returned: `[5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 0]`

Code:

```
function middleOutIterator(index, arraySize) {
    var distances = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        distances[i] = [ i, Math.abs(index - i) ];
    }

    distances.sort(sort);

    for (var i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
        distances[i] = distances[i][0];
    }

    return distances;
}

function sort(a, b) {
    return a[1] > b[1];
}
```

Basically, you pass in a starting index, and it iterates outward in either direction.

This is not a true iterator, it merely creates an array of indices, so the name I gave it is a bit of misnomer, but what would you call this kind of iteration/sorting?

I'm not looking to optimize this function as it's not in a crucial area and certainly not a bottleneck, but I am interested in reading more about it and any related algorithms.

Comment: `f(x) = n + xsin(x)`?

Comment: I would have never thought of that, it's amazing to me how some people (read: you) can bust out equations like that!  Is that what's called a Taylor series?

Comment: `xsinx + C` is just a general form for the entire class of sinusoidal functions that look like that. Taylor expansion is something entirely different.

Comment: lol, you can see how current my math skills are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of iteration was recommended in the initial paper on [Robin Hood hashing](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1986/CS-86-14.pdf), where it was used in the searching step when doing lookups. The paper refers to it as "mean-centric searching," since the idea is to jump to the (expected) middle of a range and search outwards in both directions around the mean.

I'm not sure if this is the "official" name of this technique or whether it goes by many names, but it's nice to have something to point to.